# Symbol with white background in plot legend (pt.bg has no effect)

Tags: r, legend

I'm trying to add a legend to a plot, but I cannot get the pch symbol to fill with white. `pt.bg` seems to have no effect:

```
plot(1, 1)
legend(
    x = "topright",
    legend = c("alle Messzeitpunkte", "ohne selbstinitiierte", "erwartete"),
    lty = c("solid", "dashed", "dotted"),
    pch = c(16, 1, NA),
    pt.bg = c("black", "white", NA)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pch = 1` is an empty circle and cannot be filled. `pch = 16` is a filled shape without a border. The color for both `pch = 1` and `pch = 16` is defined by `col`. Only `pch = 21` can be filled with a color different from its border color. The color of the filling of `pch = 21` is defined by `bg` in many plotting functions and `pt.bg` in `legend()`.

```
plot(1:10, rep(1, 10), ylim = c(0, 2), axes = FALSE)
legend(
    x = 1, y = 2,
    legend = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
    lty = "solid",
    pch = c(1, 1, 1),
    col = c("black", "black", "red", "red", "red"),
    pt.bg = c("black", "white", "red", "green", "blue")
)
legend(
    x = 2.5, y = 2,
    legend = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
    lty = "solid",
    pch = c(16, 16, 16),
    col = c("black", "black", "red", "red", "red"),
    pt.bg = c("black", "white", "red", "green", "blue")
)
legend(
    x = 4, y = 2,
    legend = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
    lty = "solid",
    pch = c(21, 21, 21),
    col = c("black", "black", "red", "red", "red"),
    pt.bg = c("black", "white", "red", "green", "blue")
)
```

[image]